# How to extract the price from website using excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

html

```html
    <tr>
    <td class = "pricing-description">Price:</td>
    <td class = "price base-price">
    <span>$</span>
    <span> 4.99 </span>
```

and i have tried using this code to get the value in my excel:

```
myValue = ie.document.querySelector(".price base-price[Price:]").innerText
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = myValue

Dim erow As Long
Dim ele As Object

Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

erow = Sheet1.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set objIE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.application")

searchterm = InputBox("ENTER CARTER'S SEARCH TERM")

With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "www.autozone.com"

    Do While .Busy Or _
       .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    .document.getElementsByClassName("hdinput typeAhead topSearch").item.innerText = searchterm

    .document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").Click
    Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop


    myValue = ie.document.querySelector(".price base-price[Price:]").innerText
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = myValue
```

My expected result would be to get the price from the website on the excel and once this starts working i can do it for many parts.

Comment: You should format your question, so that anyone can understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
myValue = IE.document.querySelector(".price base-price[Price:]").innerText
```

is trying to substitute an `innerText` value of a node (the previous sibling `td`) for an attribute name in your [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), along with a character which is normally used to denote pseudo (:). Also, you are missing the [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) to go with  `base-price` i.e. `.base-price`, otherwise it becomes a [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors); and, you are specifying a parent child relation by your use of [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) between the two class names when we can see that the td elements are siblings.

Here is what your selector is saying:

<sub>*click to enlarge*</sub>

[image]

You want only the direct class for the node, by the looks of it, and then access the `.innerText`:

```
myValue = IE.document.querySelector(".base-price").innerText
```

---

Additional info:

1. [Pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)